# How to add new column in Laravel's default Users table?

Tags: laravel

I modified the default laravel's user table and I did that by creating my own migration.

Here's my migration sample:

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('username', 15)->unique()->after('id');
            $table->string('lastname', 15)->unique()->after('username');
            $table->string('firstname', 15)->unique()->after('lastname');
            $table->string('contact')->nullable()->after('email');
            $table->date('birthday')->after('contact');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1)->after('birthday');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('username');
            $table->dropColumn('lastname');
            $table->dropColumn('firstname');
            $table->dropColumn('contact');
            $table->dropColumn('birthday');
            $table->dropColumn('status');
        });
    }
```

And I removed the column `name` in the default laravel table so it looks like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

I checked the values from my form in the AuthController and I dont have an issue in getting the values. Here's what I added in the AuthController

```
protected $username = 'username'; //choose username instead of email
protected $redirectPath = '/dashboard'; //if successful login
protected $loginPath = 'auth/login'; //if not login
protected $redirectAfterLogout = 'auth/login'; //redirect after login

/**
 * Create a new authentication controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'username'  => 'required|min:8|max:16|unique:users',
        'lastname'  => 'required',
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'contact'   => 'required',
        'birthday'  => 'date_format: Y-m-d',
        'email'     => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password'  => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{

    //dd($data); -- I can get all the values here

    // I added my own column in this part to save. Is it correct?
    return User::create([
        'username'  =>  $data['username'],
        'lastname'  =>  $data['lastname'],
        'firstname' =>  $data['firstname'],
        'birthday'  =>  $data['birthday'],
        'contact'   =>  $data['contact'],
        'email'     =>  $data['email'],
        'status'    =>  1,
        'password'  =>  bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

And when I try to save the data I can only save these columns

```
mysql> select * from users \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
            id: 1
      username:
      lastname:
     firstname:
         email: myemail@gmail.com
       contact: NULL
      birthday: 0000-00-00
        status: 1
      password: $2y$10$3NkmqZaje4MKzheqPZKbhOIGD7ZlqYRfIP6DJZz4zb4gXVNvFsv2W
remember_token: PCYczF2Y9ts97TvbDOLsiXO5hxkekkxysmMYuIdN5MsaIY8TnroEof6d2jVM
    created_at: 2015-09-17 06:56:43
    updated_at: 2015-09-17 07:00:35
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

ERROR:
No query specified
```

How can I add my new column in the database?

Ok that's all I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 14):

You can not edit the users table with this way
first, go to the terminal and write this command :

```
php artisan make:migration add_new_fields_to_users_table
```

and click enter.
After that, go to the migration file and in the add_new_fields_to_users_table.php
and write your new columns

```
 $table->string('username', 15)->unique()->after('id');
        $table->string('lastname', 15)->after('username');
        $table->string('firstname', 15)->after('lastname');
        $table->string('contact')->nullable()->after('email');
        $table->date('birthday')->after('contact');
        $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1)->after('birthday');
```

Then , go to the terminal and do this:

```
php artisan migrate
```

and finally go to the User model and add the name's of your new table to the fillable variable

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password','username',
    'lastname','firstname','contact','birthday','status'
];
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 7):

Ok I found the answer.
I need to put my own custom column in the fillable content:

```
 protected $fillable = ['username', 'lastname', 'firstname', 'contact',  'email', 'birthday', 'status', 'password'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Three files you need no adjust when you are adding new fields to the default users table or modifying  to the default users table:

1. `Users model` found in `Controllers\User.php` or `Controllers\Models\User.php`

> Update:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];
```

2. `Register blade` in view located in views\auth\register.blade.php
   Add new text-field for your new fields
3. `Register Controller` located at `Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php`

> Update:

`Validator function` and `create function`

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

4. `Users table` found in `database\migrations\create_users_table.php`
   Add/Modify your schema

Answer (score 0):

In the start I was able to add a role column to the users table like this.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->string("role")->default("user");
        ...
    });
}
```

I ran migrate and rollback commands several times while I was testing the application with different data. Later I needed two more columns in the user table.

Did as I had done before but failed.

Solved my problem with this artisan command and I was able to add more columns just by defining them in the user table schema as above.

**Warning:**

This rolls back all the migrations and you will lose all the data in your database. Make sure that you intentionally wanna happen this to the data.

```
php artisan migrate:reset
```